# How to give hyphen as option argument in getopt class

Tags: java

I have to give "-" as option argument in

> Getopt class

my code is given below

```
Getopt g = new Getopt("cm_log_parser", args, "i:s"); //-D to enable debug log


while((opt = g.getopt()) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 'f'://To set file name(if above is not specified)
            fileNameWithPath = getAndCheckOptArg(fFlag, opt, g);
            fFlag = true;
            break;

        case 's'://To set the header
            String separator = getAndCheckOptArg(hFlag, opt, g);
            hFlag = true;
            breakk;
        case '?':
            usage("Invalid option" + opt + " option");
            break;
    }
}
```

in the arguments I want give as -s "-" but it is showing some error like invalid option is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--` in [Getopt](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven/ostermiller-syntax/1.1.1/gnu/getopt/Getopt.java) has a special meaning

> The user can force getopt() to **stop scanning the command line with the special argument "--" by itself**. Any elements occuring before the "--" are scanned and permuted as normal. Any elements after the "--" are returned as is as non-option argv elements. For example, "foo -a -- bar -d" would return option 'a' then -1. optind would point to "foo", "bar" and "-d" as the non-option argv elements. The "--" is discarded by getopt().

So I'm afraid you won't be able to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this using `-s-` (no spaces). I don't know if Getopt allows this or not.